# Error while trying to run NiftyNet quick start command

Tags: python, niftynet

I'm trying out NiftyNet and got stuck at the first step.
Trying to run the quickstart command

> python net_download.py dense_vnet_abdominal_ct_model_zoo
>   python net_segment.py inference -c  ~/niftynet/extensions/dense_vnet_abdominal_ct/config.ini

gives me

> KeyError: "Registering two gradient with name 'FloorMod' !(Previous registration was in _find_and_load_unlocked :955)"

Could any one help? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia GPU. Tried tensorflow:1.4.1-py3 docker image, Anaconda with CPU version of tensorflow 
and native python with CPU version of tensorflow and I get the same error.

I'm pretty sure it's something I did wrong because I get the same error from those different environment but I'm not sure what...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a change from TensorFlow 1.3 (which is the official NiftyNet dependency) to 1.4. You can switch back to TF1.3, or comment out the following lines in niftynet/layer/resampler.py

```
@tf.RegisterGradient('FloorMod')
def _floormod_grad(op, grad):
    return [None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Install tensorflow using this command
pip install tensorflow
After that install nifty net using below command 
'''
pip install niftynet
'''
reinstall the python
'''
pip install python
'''
if the problem is still than please mentioned your problem in more details
please make sure your environment variable is set before executing the command from niftynet page.